# Perl Regex Problem!

Tags: regex, linux, perl, string

I am reading a string from a file:

> 2343,0,1,0 ... 500 times ...3

Above is an example of `$_` when it is read from a file. It is any number, followed by 500 comma separated 0's/1's then the number 3.

```
while(<FILE>){
    my $string = $_;
    chomp($string);
    my $a = chop($string);
    my $found;
    if($string=~m/^[0-9]*\,((0,|1,){$i})/){         
        $found = $&.$a;
        print OTH $found,"\n";
        }   
}
```

I am using `chop` to get the number 3 from the end of the string. Then matching the first number followed by `$i` occurences of 0, or 1. The problem I'm having is that `chop` is not working on the string for some reason. In the `if` statement when I try to concat the match and the chopped number all I get returned is the contents of `$&`.

I have also tried using  `my $a = substr $a,-1,1;` to get the number 3 and this also hasn't worked.

The thing that's odd is that this code works in Eclipse on Windows, and when I put it onto a Linux server it won't work. Can anyone spot the silly mistake I'm making?

Comment: Variables $a and $b are special variables used by Perl in sort routines; as a rule they should not be used outside of this.

Comment: Don't use [chop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html "perldoc -f chop"), it's not meant for this.

Comment: Don't use [`$&`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%26 "perldoc -v $&"). The use of this variable **anywhere** in a program imposes a considerable performance penalty on **all** regular expression matches.

Comment: @Brad Gilbert, thanks for that info, I am pretty new to perl this is my first project. Although I don't see why the above is not a valid use of chop. It returns the last character of the string which is what I want.

Comment: Maybe *invalid* was the wrong word, perhaps I should have said *strongly discouraged*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule, I tend always to allow for unseen whitespace in my data. I find that it makes my code more robust expecting that somebody didn't see an extra space at the end of a line or string (as in writing to a log). So I think this would solve your problem:

```
my ( $a ) = $string =~ /(\S)\s*$/;
```

Of course, since you *know* you are looking for a number, it's better to be more precise:

```
my ( $a ) = $string =~ /(\d+)\s*$/;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, although other answers raise good points, this is exactly the problem. I thought that chomp() gets rid of \n and trailing whitespace but I was wrong. That was the problem! I'l remember this rule!!

Comment: @B. Bowles, It's a rule that's served many, many parsers well over the years: ignore whitespace. (no slam on Python.) And regexes are use lexing technology to create ad-hoc tokens. If a user has *any* hand in the data: ignore--and allow for--whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Take care of the end of line char… I can not test here but I assume you just chop a newline. Try first to trim your string then chop it. See for example http://www.somacon.com/p114.php

Comment: The chomp() should be eating all the trailing whitespace.

Comment: Yeah, if the data being read has "\r\n" at the end of a line then this would happen. Instead of `chomp` try `Text::Trim::rtrim($string)` or `$string =~ s/\s+$//`

Comment: @Wes Hardaker - chomp only removes stuff that matches the value of `$/`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to do it that way, why not use a regexp to pull out everything you need in one go?

```
my $x = "4123,0,1,0,1,4";
$x =~ /^[0-9]+,((?:0,|1,){4})([0-9]+)/;
print "$1\n$2\n";
```

Produces:

```
0,1,0,1,
4
```

Which is pretty much what you're looking for.  Both sets of needed answers are in the match variables.

Note that I included ?: in the front of the 0,1, matching so that it *didn't* end up in the output match variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you are trying to achieve here but I've tried the code on Win32 and Solaris and it works. Are you sure $i is the correct number? Might be easier to use * or ?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while(<DATA>){
    my $string = $_;
    chomp($string);
    my $a = chop($string);
    print "$string\n";
    my $found;
    if($string=~m/^[0-9]*\,((0,|1,)*)/){         
        $found = $&.$a;
        print $found,"\n";
        }   
}



__DATA__
2343,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,3
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much reason to use a regex in this case, just use [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie; # open will now die on failure

my %data;

{
  # limit the scope of $fh
  open my $fh, '<', 'test.data';
  while(<$fh>){
    chomp;
    s(\s+){}g; # remove all spaces

    my($number,@bin) = split ',', $_;
    # uncomment if you want to throw away the 3
    # pop @bin if $bin[-1] == 3;
    $data{$number} = \@bin;
  }
  close $fh;
}
```

If all you want is the 3

```
while(<$fh>){
  # the .* forces it to look for the last set of numbers
  my($last_number) = /.*([0-9]+)/;
}
```